# How to use trigger to update column for newly inserted tuple

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert, create-table

I have a table BillRecords

```
bill_id        buy_amt        sell_amt        profit
----------------------------------------------------
0              200            300             NULL
1              1000           1200            NULL
```

Let's say I want to insert following record

```
INSERT INTO BillRecords(bill_id, buy_amt, sell_amt) 
VALUES (2, 2000, 2500)
```

I'm expecting that as soon as I insert record, trigger should only update profit column for newly inserted record (i.e. WHERE bill_id = 2) and not for all the rows in profit column. What should I do?

Note: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: database syntax dependent.  Create a trigger - then inside there - use the new value of the incoming row - and do your insert.

Comment: @GMB I'm using sqlserver

Comment: @Abra My question is not just how to create a trigger lol

Answer (score 4):

No need for a trigger to do what you want. It is much simpler, and more efficient, to use a computed column:

```
create table billrecords (
    bill_id  int primary key,
    buy_amt  int,
    sell_amt int,
    profit as (buy_amt - sell_amt)
);
```

Or if you want to add it to an already-existing table:

```
alter table billrecords
    add profit as (buy_amt - sell_amt);
```

This gives you an always up-to-date value, that you can access just like any other column. For better performance, you can use option `persisted`, so the value column is physically stored, and recomputed only when needed instead of every time it is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

Since you only want to update the profit amount of the transaction having bill_id = 2, you can use the below after trigger this in combination with a derived column "profit" which fetches the profit amount.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_name   
    ON billrecords      
    After INSERT   
    AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * from inserted)
     begin
     
        update  m
        set m.profit = m.sell_amt - m.bill_amt, m.bill_amt = null, m.sell_amt = null
        from billrecords m join inserted i
        on i.bill_id = m.bill_id
        where i.bill_id = 2 
     
     end;
```

Comment: here, we are hardcoding the bill_id as 2. We should have generic code in the trigger, even if go for it. computed column is the best solution for this question as GMB has provided

Comment: I think that is what Op asked to filter out specific id we can hardcode any id in the the trigger that should work fine.